# How to remove repeated nested tags using Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I have HTML with nested repeated tags:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <div>
        <div>
          <p>Some text</p>
        </div>  
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I want to remove nested repeated `div`s which don't have any attributes. The resulting HTML should look like:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <p>Some text</p>
    </div>  
  </body>
</html>
```

How can that be done using Nokogiri or pure Ruby?

Comment: Do you have to worry about attributes on the nested divs? For example, if you have `<div id="1"><div id="2"></div></div>` do you expect `<div id="1"></div>`, `<div id="2"></div>` or `<div id="1,2"></div>` or is it a non-issue?

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I only want to collapse repeated empty divs. If div has any attributes I skip those.

Comment: Please see "[ask]", "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)" and "[MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)" and all their linked pages. When asking we want to see evidence of your effort. Without that it looks like you're asking us to write code for you, instead of help fix your code.

Comment: Don't have any attributes or only have a `div` child? It's not entirely clear what you mean. In the example HTML _could_ there be intervening nodes with attributes or other non-`div` nodes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally I'm not a huge fan of mutable structures like Nokogiri uses, but in this case I think it works in your advantage. Something like this might work:

```rb
def recurse node
  # depth first so we don't accidentally modify a collection while
  # we're iterating through it.
  node.elements.each do |child|
    recurse(child)
  end

  # replace this element's children with it's grandchildren
  # assuming it meets all the criteria
  if merge_candidate?(node)
    node.children = node.elements.first.children
  end
end

def merge_candidate? node, name: 'div'
  return false unless node.element?
  return false unless node.attributes.empty?
  return false unless node.name == name
  return false unless node.elements.length == 1
  return false unless node.elements.first.name == name
  return false unless node.elements.first.attributes.empty?

  true
end
```

```rb
[18] pry(main)> file = File.read('test.html')
[19] pry(main)> doc = Nokogiri.parse(file)
[20] pry(main)> puts doc
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <div>
        <div>
          <p>Some text</p>
        </div>  
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
[21] pry(main)> recurse(doc)
[22] pry(main)> puts doc
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <p>Some text</p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
=> nil
[23] pry(main)>
```

Comment: Rather than toss out code please explain how it works and why it should be the selected answer. The goal is to do more than simply satisfy the need for code but to educate the OP and others who find this answer in the future.

Comment: What problem is there with Nokogiri's use of a mutable DOM? That's its reason for existence, to parse, search and manipulate the HTML or XML. And it also supports SAX and building XML/HTML nicely.

Comment: I don't feel like that was "tossed out code". It is commented and it works.

Comment: There are bunch of edge cases to consider but I think your answer is correct as a general direction and is helpful. Thank you GSP!

Answer (score 1):

Based on how your HTML is structured this should get you going:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(<<EOT)
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <div>
        <div>
          <p>Some text</p>
        </div>  
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html> 
EOT

dd = doc.at('div div').parent
dp = dd.at('div p')
dd.children.unlink
dp.parent = dd
```

Which results in:

```
puts doc.to_html

# >> <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
# >> <html>
# >>   <head>
# >>     <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
# >>   </head>
# >>   <body>
# >>     <div><p>Some text</p></div>
# >>   </body>
# >> </html>
```

`dd` is the [`parent`](https://nokogiri.org/rdoc/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#parent-instance_method) for two successive `div` tags, in other words it's the first `div` in the chain.

`dp` is the `p` node at the end of that chain.

`dd.children` is a NodeSet containing the [`children`](https://nokogiri.org/rdoc/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#children-instance_method) of `dd`, all the way down to, and including, `dp`.

The idea is to graft `dp`, (the desired `<p>` node), to `dd`, (the topmost `<div>` node), after removing all the other intervening `<div>` tags. A [NodeSet](https://nokogiri.org/rdoc/Nokogiri/XML/NodeSet.html) makes it easy to [`unlink`](https://nokogiri.org/rdoc/Nokogiri/XML/NodeSet.html#unlink-instance_method) large numbers of tags at once.

Read about [`at`](https://nokogiri.org/rdoc/Nokogiri/XML/Searchable.html#at-instance_method) to understand why it's significant for this sort of problem.